# How do I write a program to swap a character in the input file with a character specified on the command line?

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write a program to swap a character that I would specify on the command line (a command line argument) with a character in the input text file. The first command line argument is the character I want to change, the second argument is character that I want to replace the old character with, and the third argument is the input file.

When I do this, my program should generate an output file named: "translation.txt". I know that the problem with my program is in the "if" statements/the fprintf statements, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I was thinking of reading each character in the input file separately, and from there, I wanted to use "if" statements to determine whether or not to replace the character.

```
void replace_character(int arg_list, char *arguments[])
{
   FILE *input, *output;

   input = fopen(arguments[3], "r");
   output = fopen("translation.txt", "w");

   if (input == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error: file cannot be opened\n");
   }

   for (int i = 0; i != EOF; i++)
   {
      if (input[i] == arguments[1])
      {
         fprintf(output, "%c\n", arguments[2]);
      }
      else
      {
         fprintf(output, "%c\n", arguments[1]);
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc < 5)
   {
      perror("Error!\n");
   }

   replace_character(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You can't index a file pointer struct.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the problems I'm having. :( I want to compare each character to my command line argument, but I'm having trouble with how to do that.

Comment: You don't actually know how to read input in C, do you?

Comment: I'm pretty new to working with files and such, so far, all I've learned is opening files for reading/writing, printing error messages when files cannot be opened, and simple things like that. :(

Comment: mmap, right?  Seems like the most straightforward way.. once you get it to work :)  It's hard.. but once it works, it's super easy!  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: I'm doing this as practice for class and I don't think we can use mmap. :( But, is there a way to do this with "fgets"? Or is there a way to read each character separately??

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != EOF; i++)` - how are you going to terminate that loop? EOF is -1 on my machine, it's never going to finish.

Comment: Hmm...would I have to use a "while" loop instead of a for loop? I've heard that it's more common to see "while" loops when working with files. But if I use a while loop, I have to read the input file before that first right?

Comment: No, it can be a while loop without any problem, e.g. something like `while ((c = fgetc(filehandle)) != EOF)` - this reads one character at a time I think it could work in your case.

Comment: OK, not to be snide, but the Unix command "tr" will do exactly what you want, unless you prefer to go through the programming exercise.  Do a "man tr" for details.

Comment: I think I would rather go through the exercise, it's practice for an upcoming test. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I think this can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 4) return -1; /* quit if argument list not there */

    FILE* handle = fopen(argv[3], "r+"); /* open the file for reading and updating */

    if (handle == NULL) return -1; /* if file not found quit */

    char current_char = 0;
    char to_replace = argv[1][0]; /* get the character to be replaced */
    char replacement = argv[2][0]; /* get the replacing character */

    while ((current_char  = fgetc(handle)) != EOF) /* while it's not the end-of-file */
    {                                              /*   read a character at a time */

        if (current_char == to_replace) /* if we've found our character */
        {
            fseek(handle, ftell(handle) - 1, SEEK_SET); /* set the position of the stream
                                                           one character back, this is done by
                                                           getting the current position using     
                                                           ftell, subtracting one from it and 
                                                           using fseek to set a new position */

            fprintf(handle, "%c", replacement); /* write the new character at the new position */
        }
    }

    fclose(handle); /* it's important to close the file_handle 
                       when you're done with it to avoid memory leaks */

    return 0;
}
```

Given an input specified as the first argument, it will seek a character to replace and then replace it with what is stored in `replacement`. Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work. I run it like this:

`./a.out l a input_trans.txt`

My file has just the string 'Hello, World!'. After running this it's changed to 'Heaao, Worad!'.

Read up on [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) and [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/), as they're key here for what you need to do.

EDIT: Forgot to add an `fclose` statement that closes the file handle at the end of the program. Fixed!

Comment: If something is unclear in the above code, I'll be more than happy to explain.

Comment: Thank you so much! One thing though, is there a way to do this without using "ftell" and "fseek"?

Comment: Not that I know of, once you've found your character, when you use `fprintf` it will write to the **next** character, so we need to backtrack one character to replace the correct one.

There is also `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` for this sort of thing but I'm not very familiar with them, AFAIK they do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, but if I put it into another function, rather than putting everything in main, would I need an else statement to account for the characters that have to stay the same?

Comment: 1. If it's a void function, you don't need to return anything. In void `return` is used like so - `return;` and only when you need to quit the function earlier than anticipated (for example you've found an error and there's no need to proceed further). In your case I recommend you leave the validation part to `main` and then put the rest in the void function. Also, you probably meant `return 0;`, not `return '/0';` as this returns a `char` and it's also not valid (you're thinking of `\0` the terminating character).

Comment: 2. Do you mean if you didn't find the character that needs to be replaced? In this case the program will not do anything, no need for `else`.

Comment: No, the characters that stay need to stay the same will not be touched, the `if` part only works on the character that is to be replaced (sorry I answered before I saw your comment edit).

Comment: It's fine, thanks! And just curious, but if I were to use "fgets" instead, how would my code change??

Comment: `fgets` seems better suited for reading strings, not single characters, but again you would go through a loop, read the number of characters you need (in your case 2) and instead of `stdin` you will pass your file handle as its third argument. Maybe something like so `while(fgets(char_array, 2, file_handle) != EOF)`. But as it reads a char array, it appends a null terminating character to the pointer it returns, so you would need to strip that and assign to a simple `char` variable. More info here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Let me know if I've missed something, otherwise I wouldn't mind if you were to accept my answer if it's been of real help :)

Comment: It's definitely helped! Thank you so much! I've accepted it. :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)