# How to swap characters in a file specified (file name and characters) in the command line?

Tags: c, file, command-line, io

I'm learning about file commands and trying to write some programs. I want to specify two characters in command line, where the second one will replace the first one, every time the first character is found. The command line input would be `[program_name].exe [file].txt [old_char] [new_char]`. I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868439/how-do-i-write-a-program-to-swap-a-character-in-the-input-file-with-a-character) which had the same problem and I tried to fix my code by looking at the answer, but it creates an infinite loop.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *string = {"Hellx"};
    char c;
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "w")) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(string, fp);
        printf("Successfully written.\n");
        fclose(fp);

        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+")) != NULL)
        {
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            {
                if (c == *argv[2])
                {
                    fseek(fp, ftell(fp) - 1, SEEK_SET);
                    fprintf(fp, "%c", *argv[3]);
                    printf("Successfully changed.\n");
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
            printf("Error on opening!");
    }
    else
        printf("Error on writing!");
    return 0;
}
```

So the output for this would be: `Helloelloelloelloelloelloello...`, while it should just change `x` to `o`. What's the problem with this code?

Comment: You need to declare `int c`, not `char c`

Comment: You don't need to use `ftell()`. If you want to go back 1 character, use `fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: ...but you need another file positioning operation or `fflush` before you switch back from writing to reading.

Comment: @WeatherVane That seems like it should be an answer.

Comment: Don't do this.  A process should never open a file for reading and writing unless it is an interactive editor.  (A slightly opinionated view.)  Instead of messing around with seeking and dealing with all the other issues, just write to a different file, and then relink the file when you're done.  This makes your program much more robust (if it dies in the middle, it won't corrupt your file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-160) for `fopen()`, in the section which discusses file opening modes, says

> When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. **When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function.**
>
> (my bolding)

So I suggest adding

```
fflush(fp);
```

after the `fprintf()` statement, as no repositioning is needed.

---

As mentioned, you also should change the type to

```
int c;
```

so that EOF `-1` can be distinguished from data `0xFF`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a short way to do this without `"r+"` and without `fflush`?

Comment: What I would do with a text file myself, is never tamper with an existing file (except as a last resort, after making a copy). I would read the old file and create a new one with the necessary changes. I would use `fgets()` to read a line, look for the characters, overwrite any, and write the same or changed string to the new file. Or you could perhaps more easily do it character by character. For a binary file with fixed size records that's another matter.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because you do not call `fseek()` or `rewind()` when switching from writing back to reading. Also note that you do not need to call `ftell()` to step back: you can use `-1L` and `SEEK_CUR`. It is also safer to open the file in binary more for this kind of file patching in place.

Furthermore, `fgetc()` returns an `int` value that does not *fit* in a `char`. Use `int` type for `c` to detect `EOF` reliably. Also note that the byte value returned by `fgetc()` when successful is the value of an `unsigned char` so comparing it to a `char` might fail for non-ASCII bytes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    const char *string = { "Hellx" };

    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf("missing command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    unsigned char c1 = argv[2][0];
    unsigned char c2 = argv[3][0];

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s for writing\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    fputs(string, fp);
    printf("Successfully written.\n");
    fclose(fp);
    
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot reopen %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == c1) {
            fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc(c2, fp);
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
            printf("Successfully changed.\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for why your program is failing were already extensively debated and solved in other answers and comments.

> *Is there a short way to do this without "r+" and without fflush?*

There is, more than one, here is an example where the file is opened to read and write, this way there is no need to always be opening and closing it, using `w+` flag, it will also create the file if it doesn't exist:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    char *string = {"Hellx"};
    if (argc > 3)
    {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "w+")) != NULL) // open to write and read
        {

            fputs(string, fp);
            printf("Successfully written.\n");           
            rewind(fp); // back to the beginning of the file
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            {
                if(c == argv[2][0]) // if the character exists...
                { 
                    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                    fprintf(fp, "%c", argv[3][0]); // replace
                    printf("Successfully changed.\n");
                    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Error on writing!");
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments!");
}
```

#### Footnote:

I agree with [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752055/how-to-swap-characters-in-file-when-theyre-specified-in-command-line/66752419#comment117998468_66752055) and [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752055/how-to-swap-characters-in-a-file-specified-file-name-and-characters-in-the-com/66752419#comment117998492_66752226), a more robust way to do this would be to use two different files.